# Cast to Type from Config

Tags: c#

Given a dictionary that maps some ID to a type:

```
Dictionary<int, Type> processIdToTypeMapping
```

I'm trying to iterate through the dictionary and cast an object to the type specified in the dictionary. The object comes from an MSMQ.

Here's how I'm iterating the dictionary:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Type> processIdToType in processIdToTypeMapping)
```

I've tried to use generics:

```
private void CreateObject<T>()
{
    FooBase fooBase = message.Body as T;
}
```

But that requires knowing the type at compile time. I can't call CreateObject() like this:

```
CreateObject<typeof(processIdToType.Value)>();  // That can't work.
```

I tried using ChangeType():

```
private void CreateObject(Type fooType)
{
    FooBase fooBase = Convert.ChangeType(message.Body, fooType);
}
```

But I get a compile time error that it can't convert.

And I tried **as**:

```
private void CreateObject(Type fooType)
{
    FooBase fooBase = message.Body as typeof(fooType);
}
```

How can I cast message.Body to the type in the dictionary?

Comment: I understand this may not be your point, but in your examples, you want to dynamically cast as a type, but then assume whatever that type is, it can be implicitly cast to `FooBase`... which seems to suggest `message.Body` is at least of `FooBase`, and thus dynamic conversion is unnecessary.

Comment: That's correct, and that's a good point. I'll need to see if casting to FooBase is good enough. I was trying to cast to the concrete type because this is automated test code and I want to verify that the message on the queue is indeed the correct concrete type.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? When you manage to threat your instance as a certain type, then what? Since at compile time you still dont know what type it is, you're basically limited in using any of its specifications. edit, oh i see :)

Comment: @BobHorn And to that extent, you can just check the type by doing `if(message.Body != null && message.Body.GetType() == fooType) ...`

Comment: Ahhhh... good call. I'll try that.

Comment: If you actually need to invoke any members on message.Body, you might want to try `dynamic`.

Comment: Right, I was wondering/hoping if this was possible without resorting to dynamic.

Comment: @HackedByChinese Your solution worked well. If you want to add it as an answer, I'll accept. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you are only trying to do dynamic type checking, so fortunately, dynamic casting is not necessary.

```
if(message.Body != null && message.Body.GetType() == fooType) ...
```